# How to know if a number is a multiple of other number?

Tags: integers

I think the definition of a multiple of a number is:
If A is a multiple of B then it's possible to represent A as A= B* X, where X is an Integer.
(A and B are also integers)

Since X must be an integer the division of A/B (X =A/B) must be an integer, otherwise A is not multiple of B.

If the division A/B is NOT an integer
then A is NOT multiple of B.

Is this true?

I know that if the remainder of a number by another number is equal to 0 then they are multiple. But I'm not interested in that way to know if two numbers are multiple of each other.

Comment: There is no general procedure that can tell you whether a number is a multiple of another number. Of course if $B=2$ or $B=5$ it can be done, but if say $B = 137$ you just have do the math (division) to see if the remainder is zero..

Comment: Your claim is false: If $A$ and $B$ are both $0,\,A\div B$ isn't an integer although $A$ is a multiple of $B.$